# Is it possible to create a very simple for loop in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

While still new to Robot, is it possible to create a very simple for loop in Robot Framework?  I have a very simple robot program and would like to run it 10 times.  I just need an example of how this can be done with a simple program.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
*** Settings ***
Library                example.py


*** Test Cases ***
Example test case 1
  Run example_test
```

Basically, I just want to loop Run example_test 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

```
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    10
\    example_test # assuming example_test is a keyword
```

Note: You can only use the for loop once in a script. If you want to use it more than once, you have to put it in a keyword.

Comment: Thanks @Dandekar! However, it still only runs for only 1 iteration for some reason.

Comment: Is example_test a keyword? maybe try `Run Keyword    example_test` or `Run Keyword and return status    example_test`. You have to extract your test case as a keyword to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a *test* in a loop, you can only run *keywords* in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's perfect article about loops in RF:
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/05/robot-framework-tutorial-loops-conditional-execution-and-more/

```
*** Test Cases ***
For-Loop-In-Range
    : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    3
    \    Log    ${INDEX}
    \    ${RANDOM_STRING}=    Generate Random String    ${INDEX}
    \    Log    ${RANDOM_STRING}

For-Loop-Elements
    @{ITEMS}    Create List    Star Trek    Star Wars    Perry Rhodan
    :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{ITEMS}
    \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
    \    ${ELEMENT}    Replace String    ${ELEMENT}    ${SPACE}    ${EMPTY}
    \    Log    ${ELEMENT}

For-Loop-Exiting
    @{ITEMS}    Create List    Good Element 1    Break On Me    Good Element 2
    :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{ITEMS}
    \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${ELEMENT}' == 'Break On Me'    Exit For Loop
    \    Log    Do more actions here ...
```

Comment: I did see this online, but I still don't get it very well.  This is why I am asking for a very simple way of looping my test case above.  Helps me to wrap my head around the concept better.